# Xamarin Currency Converter Allow Negative

Tags: c#, xamarin, converters

I have a currency converter class to convert entry input into currency. However, I would like to allow for negative values as well.

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Price, Converter={StaticResource currencyConverter}}" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="$0.00""/>
```

```
public class CurrencyConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Decimal.Parse(value.ToString()).ToString("C");
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string valueFromString = Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), @"\D", "");

            if (valueFromString.Length <= 0)
                return 0m;

            long valueLong;
            if (!long.TryParse(valueFromString, out valueLong))
                return 0m;

            if (valueLong <= 0)
                return 0m;

            return valueLong / 100m;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the approach with your regular expression then.

Instead of replacing all non-digit characters try to capture digits with possible leading dash.

The regex for this is: `^-?\d+$`
[image]

You can look how this regex works [here](https://regex101.com/r/dInlwr/1)

And the using of it is a little bit different.

```
string valueFromString = Regex.Match("", @"^-?\d+$").Value;
```

And the last think: you should remove the last condition, because if the input value would be less than zero, zero would be returned.

```
if (valueLong <= 0)
    return 0m;
```

I don't know the rest of the logic into your app, but those would be first steps.

Comment: I tried using that regex but it's just giving me "" when I type in a number, for example, "$00.02"

Comment: Is there a regex I can use to accept only digits or parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

According to the requirements you described, you just want to convert the input number to Decimal type.

1. You only need to judge whether the input number is negative in the method, if it is negative, you only need to **replace** the string.
2. In order to make the code simpler, you can use the `Completed` method of Entry and judge it internally.

I wrote a small example for your reference:

Here is the background code(Check where notes are added):

```
 private void Entry_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int myenry =  int.Parse((sender as Entry).Text.ToString());
        string returnEntry = Decimal.Parse(mytest.Text.ToString()).ToString("C");
        if (myenry < 0) //Judge here and perform string replacement
        {
            returnEntry = returnEntry.Insert(2,"-");
        }
        mytest1.Text = returnEntry;
    }
```

Comment: So the problem is I want the input to be masked as currency, which is what that converter class is doing.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean very much. Do you mean that you want to modify it every time you enter it?

Comment: And for you want to change the value into a plural, the comment in the code I provided can end this problem.

Comment: The converter class I posted is masking the user input so it's always in the format $##.## but I don't know how to have it display negative numbers

Comment: You only need to use the code in the if method I provided.

Comment: First judge your value, and then add a negative sign to Decimal.Parse(value.ToString()).ToString("C");.

Comment: Right, but I need it to display as a negative value to the user in the entry field as well. i.e. ($1.00) to indicate it's negative

Comment: returnEntry = returnEntry.Insert(2,"-"); This line of code is to add a minus sign to your string

Comment: The returnEntry in my code is equivalent to the value you need to return.

Comment: Has the problem been resolved?